# How to answer a "Is this correct" question?

Tags: discussion

I am thinking about the post [What is the probability of an XX female or XY male?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/50418/what-is-the-probability-of-an-xx-female-or-xy-male).

How are we supposed to answer this question other than by just stating "Yes you are correct"? One can probably teach the OP something but it would probably be off-topic as not specifically asked for by the OP.

Comment: skeptics.se is a good branch to for questions like 'is this correct or a myth?' type questions.

Comment: If the OP is incorrect, then the mistake or the blind-corner could be clarified/ marked. If it is a very simple question with well-known answers, then it could be moved/ request to move in chat. But if the verification-question is not so simple (rather the asker meant it just as a possibility (eg. http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/251104/tv-screen-in-still-photo-why-are-there-dark-blackish-bands) then it could be discussed.